# Action hooked on wp_enqueue_scripts running twice

Tags: wordpress

I disabled all plugins on my wordpress and keept only my very simple theme active. On functions.php I let running the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    // Omitted some code - Here I just call a custom function to print logs
    wp_debug_backtrace_summary(); // Just indicating that I call this function on log

    // The script exists and is correctly added to the frontend
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}, 101 );
```

On the log, I get that this function run twice - you can see above two payloads from `wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`:

```
[2020-02-10 20:58:37 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)


=====================================================================

[2020-02-10 20:58:37 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/index.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)
```

I notice the item 18 on both backtrace are different:

```
[18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
[18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/index.php')
```

If I comment the code line that enqueue the script `wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', ... )` The payload I get says my function run only once!

```
[2020-02-10 21:13:21 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. Why is running twice?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an anonymous function for the callback on wp_enqueue_scripts and you'll probably solve your problem.

[WP Coding standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/)

Closures must not be passed as filter or action callbacks, as they cannot be removed by remove_action() / remove_filter()

Comment: I used anonymous function only in this question, just to make it smaller. I'm not using in my actual code. Unsing it or not, it just don't affect the problem at all.